# how can I demonstrate a succession with a floor function by induction?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Show that for $n \geq 1$ it is satisfied that.

$$\lfloor{\frac{1}{2}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{2}{2}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{3}{2}}\rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor = \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the lower integer part of $x$ (floor function evaluated at $x$).

any idea to start to make it,

Comment: On the left side, continue the pattern for n+1, and on the right side, add whatever you did to the left side and rewrite using some basic distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider two cases.
Case $1$: $n=2k$

$$\lfloor{\frac{1}{2}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{2}{2}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{3}{2}}\rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor =$$

$$0+1+1+2+2+...+(k-1)+k =$$

$$k^2= \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rfloor$$

Case $2$: $n=2k+1$
$$\lfloor{\frac{1}{2}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{2}{2}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{3}{2}}\rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor =$$

$$0+1+1+2+2+...+k+k =$$

$$k (k+1)= \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rfloor$$

Comment: Hello, try \left \lfloor \right \rfloor for larger floor symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Prove the base case for $n=1$, then:

Assume that, for some $k \in \mathbb N$,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{1}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{2}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{3}2\right\rfloor+\cdots + \left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor$$

Then for the $n=k+1$ case,

$$\begin{align*}
LHS &= \left\lfloor\frac{1}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{2}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{3}2\right\rfloor+\cdots + \left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor \left(\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor +1\right)\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac{k}2+1\right\rfloor\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac{k+2}2\right\rfloor\\
&= RHS
\end{align*}$$